# Using subqueries for locale fallback in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, localization, subquery

I have a hosted online store product that supports custom fields for various data types. Cutting to the chase, anyone can add extra key/value pairs to any record by adding to a table that is defined as:

```
`storeId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`locale` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`table` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`key` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`value` mediumblob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`storeId`, `locale`, `table`, `id`, `key`)
```

In Europe, lots of people want to support multiple languages, so each key can have multiple values for different locales. Each store will have a default locale (designated by the store owner) and an active locale (chosen by the customer).

The query I'm trying to put together behaves like so:

- The `storeId`, `table` and `id` are all known, as are the active locale and default locale.
- If a value for a key is not available for the active locale, the value for the default locale is returned instead.
- If a value for the default locale is also not available, return the value for *any* other locale.

I've come up with a pretty awkward query that achieves the desired result. Let's say the store ID is `1`, the table is `Products`, and the ID is `gadget1`; the default locale is `en_AU` and the active locale is `de_DE`. Here's what we'd query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT `key`, `value` 
    FROM nf_CustomFields 
    WHERE `storeId` = 1
        AND `table` = 'Products'
        AND `id` = 'gadget1'
    ORDER BY `locale`='de_DE' DESC, 
        `locale`='en_AU' DESC
    ) 
AS a 
GROUP BY `key`;
```

This works, but it's ugly and seems inefficient. I know there's a better way but I can't put my finger on it.

Can anybody suggest something better?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've done similar things in the past. I set it up a bit differently though: each thing had its original/default language and then a set of translations. That way you don't have your third option, either they their language or they get the item's native language. OTOH, `en_AU` does have a certain appeal in the UK :)

Comment: OK so it turns out what I was doing was about the best thing to do anyway. Oh well. A man can dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try LEFT JOINing `nf_CustomFields` to itself and then use COALESCE to ignore the NULLs that the LEFT JOIN will produce if there are no native language rows. Something like this (untested and possibly not working) query:

```
select coalesce(nl.`key`,   def.`key`),
       coalesce(nl.`value`, def.`value`)
from nf_CustomFields nl
left outer join nfCustomFields def
     on nl.`store`  = def.`store`
    and nl.`table`  = def.`table`
    and nl.`id`     = def.`id`
    and nl.`locale` = 'de_DE'
 where def.`locale` = 'en_AU'
   and def.`id`     = KNOWN
   and def.`store`  = KNOWN
   and def.`table`  = KNOWN
```

The `KNOWN` would, of course, be replaced with your known values and you'd use real dynamic values in place of `'de_DE'` and `'en_AU'` of course.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll give it a whirl but I'm not sure that it allows for plan C (fall back to any available locale). Cheers!

Comment: @Neil: I'm pretty sure you could extend that approach to allow for the "any available language" stuff. Another LEFT JOIN, rejig the join conditions and WHERE, and add another column to the COALESCE calls. It wouldn't be pretty but it should work and perform okay with the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll do some benchmarking and get back to you :)

Comment: This performed a little less efficiently than what I originally had but as there were no other ideas, I'll accept it because I think it's a good, creative idea anyway :)

Comment: @Neil: You can answer your own question and accept that answer if you have something better.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I've always found that a little narcissistic :)

Comment: @Neil: Depends how good your answer is really. I do like using `en_AU` for the Brits in any case, a little bit of colony-revenge :)